# Python idle syntax highlighting

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm using idle on windows 7 as I've just come from a mac and the text editor I was using highlighted different keywords then what idle does. I know that I can change the colour of the current syntax like print and def but can I add other keywords to highlight as well? Thanks

Comment: which text editor were you using on Mac? Perhaps it has a Windows version.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think Idle is extensible in that way, without hacking on its source code. I believe that it currently highlights only a specific set of names (plus other easily identifiable things like string literals).

- It highlights in orange (by default) all of the [keywords of the Python language](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).
- It highlights in magenta all of the built-in functions, types and other objects that are available from the standard library without doing any `import` statements. (You can see a list of them by running `dir(__builtins__)` in a Python interpreter, or by browsing sections 2-6 of the [Library Reference](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html).)

Idle does not do much code analysis. This means that it can't tell what most other names represent. It can't give specific highlighting colors to, for example, class names, because there's no requirement for them to be named in any particular way. Does `foo` in your code refer to a class, a module, a function or something else? Idle can't tell.

If you want more serious highlighting, you may need to find a more sophisticated IDE. I've recently been pretty happy with [Spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) (though I'm not sure if its syntax highlighting is any more capable than Idle's), and there are lots of others. The official Python wiki has [a list of IDEs](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments) which might help you find the one that is best for you.

Comment: so i was able to add part of what i wanted by adding about 9 characters to the source code.  When i have a bit more time next week, i'll add the rest of what i want but that's going to be a lot more complicated